# How to print a length function on a new line? (fundamentals)

Tags: python, line, new-operator

I'm going back through Python Crash Course 2nd Edition for about the third time to cement my knowledge, & I've run into something interesting that I haven't actually accounted for in previous runs. When printing a lists length with the len() function, I realized I am not exactly sure how to perform this on a new line in this situation, so I added a separate print function above it that begins a new line itself. This causes the next line to be pushed down yet *another* line, as I'm assuming the line that is supposed to have my length on it, doesn't want to take its place  where the previous print function already is, making 2 spacer lines. Is there a specific way I can print the length of this list on a new line without utilizing a separate print function?

I apologize if this seems silly. My code is as follows:

```
# -- Temporarily sort a list in alphabetical order -- #
colleges = ['Suffolk', 'Westbury', 'Maritime']
print("\nHere is the original list:")
print(*colleges, sep=', ')
print("\nHere is the temporarily sorted list:")
print(*sorted(colleges), sep=', ')
print("\nHere is the original list again:")
print(*colleges, sep=', ')

# -- Sorts list in reverse order, not alphabetically -- #
print("\nHere is a reversed list, not in alphabetical order:")
colleges.reverse()
print(*colleges, sep=', ')

# -- Printing the length of the list -- #
print("\n")
print(len(colleges))
```

I appreciate any help! These fundamentals are important to me.

Answer (score 2):

The `print()` function automatically ends with a newline character (`\n`).

Then

```
print("\n")
print(len(colleges))
```

Equals

```
\n\nlen(colleges)\n
```

To achieve what you need you can make use of the extra arguments of `print()`. Like so:

```
print('\n', len(colleges))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a specific way I can print the length of this list on a new line without utilizing a separate print function?

Omitting the print function preceding `print(len(colleges))` will do the job.
The preceding `print("\n")` will print a new line, *and* end with a newline, hence the 2-line spacer.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print - all print statements end with a newline by default.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the \n function. The len function automatically does this for you.

The reason why it does this is because all print statements automatically does this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
# -- Printing the length of the list -- #
str = "\n" + str(len(colleges))
print(str)
```

Here is another:

```
# -- Printing the length of the list -- #
print()
print(len(colleges))
```

In general, any solution will involve changing this line somehow because it will always print two lines:

```
print("\n")
```